# I've failed to install the R package, broken packages

Tags: apt, package-management, dependencies, r

```
gui@pcgui:~$ sudo apt-get install r-base
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base : Depends: r-base-core (>= 3.5.1-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Depends: r-recommended (= 3.5.1-1bionic) but it is not going to be installed
          Recommends: r-base-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

I dont what to do.

and, I've found the solution which failed to help me,
if i input

```
gui@pcgui:~/Downloads$ sudo apt install r-base-core
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 r-base-core : Depends: libblas3 but it is not installable or
                        libblas.so.3 but it is not installable
               Depends: libcurl4 (>= 7.28.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: liblapack3 but it is not installable or
                        liblapack.so.3 but it is not installable
               Depends: libtcl8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not installable
               Depends: libtk8.6 (>= 8.6.0) but it is not installable
               Recommends: r-recommended but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-base-dev but it is not going to be installed
               Recommends: r-doc-html but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

and, for last, i've encountered a situation which asked me [Y/n] and I input Y and it aborted.

Comment: Please run `sudo apt install -f`

Comment: Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.

Comment: What is your Ubuntu version? Also please add output of `apt-cache policy r-base r-base-core` to the question. How did you got R 3.5 while Ubuntu Bionic [has 3.4.4](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&section=all&arch=any&keywords=r-base-core&searchon=names)?

Answer (score 0):

I was getting a similar message when trying to install 3.5.2 over 3.4.4. 
I had to

```
sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list`
Then added a # to the line 
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu xenial-cran35/
```

Then I added a new line 
`

```
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/
```

Then I saved that and ran the following

```
sudo apt-get clean
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install r-base r-recommended r-cran-*
```

That seems to have fixed one of the issues I was having but I am still having an issue install libxml2-dev in R.

Comment: didn't work :( any other alternative?